# What's the client.javascript.plugins for Rollbar payload?

Tags: rollbar

I am checking actual [Rollber](https://rollbar.com) payload data from the browser comes. 
I had checked the official document before. however, it has some unknown data like below.

- [API Reference - Items (POST)](https://rollbar.com/docs/api/items_post/)

Payload data(excerpt of `client` property is as follows):

```
...

"client": {
  "timestamp": 1488857872,
  "javascript": {
    "language": "ja-jp",
    "screen": {
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 1080
    },
    "guess_uncaught_frames": true,
    "plugins": [{ // What's that?
            "name": "AdobeAAMDetect",
            "description": "Creative Cloud Desktop Plugin.v_3_0_0_0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-in, Version 15.023.20056",
            "description": "Adobe\u00ae Acrobat\u00ae Plug-in for Web Browsers, Version 15.023.20056"
        },
        {
            "name": "Default Browser Helper",
            "description": "\u30c7\u30d5\u30a9\u30eb\u30c8 Web \u30d6\u30e9\u30a6\u30b6\u306b\u95a2\u3059\u308b\u60c5\u5831\u3092\u63d0\u4f9b\u3057\u307e\u3059"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shockwave Flash",
            "description": "Shockwave Flash 21.0 r0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Applet Plug-in",
            "description": "Displays Java applet content, or a placeholder if Java is not installed."
        },
        {
            "name": "WebKit \u5185\u8535 PDF",
            "description": ""
        }
    ],
    "source_map_enabled": true,
    "code_version": "915",
    "cookie_enabled": true,
    "browser": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/537.86.7"
  },
  "runtime_ms": 225
},

...
```

I want to make clear the `client.javascript.plugins` data where is them came from and how the Rollbar get those data.

Comment: Hi there - I'm on the Rollbar team, and we'd be glad to help you out.  The best way to get an answer is by emailing us via support@rollbar.com.  That way the right person on our team will be sure to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for the Rollbar javascript library, you can see that the plugin data comes from these lines:

https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js/blob/v2.1.3/src/browser/transforms.js#L83,L98

The data comes from the plugin array which is a property of the navigator object in most browsers, c.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins

Comment: thanks. I communicated with the Rollbar team via email. then I got the same answer.